# I have a Model 36050 telescope

Tags: planet, telescope, amateur-observing

My Model 36050 telescope came with the H6mm, H20mm and the green filtered moon lenses. It has a 360mm focal length and a 50mm diamiter.  What can be seen with it?

Comment: Have you checked the Amazon reviews? Have you tried looking at the moon?

Comment: It'll get you the Galilean moons of Jupiter, Saturn's ring, the phases of Venus, nice views of moon, several good open clusters and a globular cluster or two. Nebula in Orion and Galaxy in Andromeda (M31) will still look like a fuzzy patches. Alcor and Mizar will look pretty: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizar_and_Alcor

Answer (score 3):

With this scope you will be able to see quite a few things. Unfortunately, you won't be able to resolve much detail with some objects.

At 50mm aperture, the light gathering ability is not fantastic. That being said, some brighter objects will be easily seen. Your max power (zoom) is approximately 2*aperture, and the power is your objective focal length (360) / eyepiece focal length. Say you have a 6mm eyepiece in, your power (zoom) will be 360/6 = 60

**PLANETS**

Mercury and Venus will be easily seen with your telescope, at the highest power, you may be able to resolve some of the phases of Venus.

Mars will be visible as a reddish round blob, with hazy edges.

Jupiter will be visible along with the 4 Galilean moons (Io, Ganymeade, Europa, Callisto), although cloud bands will be very hard to resolve. Perhaps if you are at a dark sky site with perfect seeing, you may be able to make out a faint cloud band, but you will likely be looking at a large bright dot, with 4 smaller ones near it. A handy app for your phone called 'Moons of Jupiter' will allow you to tell which ones you are looking at.

Saturn will be a nice sight as you will be able to see the rings. This is always a spectacular sight for newcomers to astronomy. Although it will be rather small (even at maximum power), it will still be a nice sight.

Uranus and Neptune will likely be too dim for you to see. In a dark sky site in great conditions, you may be able to make out a tiny dim dot for each, but that is unlikely.

**DSO's (Deep Sky Objects)**

For DSO's, your best bet is to go for clusters and nebula at around mag +6.5-+7 max. Any dimmer than that and you will struggle. This means you will be able to see such globular clusters as the great cluster in Hercules, the Andromeda galaxy and the Orion nebula (these 3 were picked as they are the brightest in their categories) although they will look like just fain smudges.

**Stars**

Some of the brighter Carbon stars are a nice sight as they are often pleasing shades of red, which distinguish them from background stars. Binary stars are also a popular sight. There are a lot of good lists of binary stars online, although you will want to go for ones with a large separation between them, so that you will be able to see both. Mizar and Alcor are a good starting point for binary stars, these are easy to locate in the handle of the 'Big Dipper' in Ursa Major. If you want a bit more from your binary stars, you could look for some colour contrasting binaries, such as Albiero in Cygnus, which is a lovely binary star with one blue and one gold star.

Some open star clusters may be nice to go for, such as the Beehive cluster in Cancer, or the Pleiades in Taurus.

The best thing to do is to download a few apps, get yourself a star chart and get to a local dark sky sight and see what you can see. There are hundreds of objects you will be able to see. You could also look for a local Astronomy group based in your location for further guidance and also a chance to look through some other telescopes too!

Oh and let us not forget the Moon! That is always a beautiful sight!

Comment: An 8x50 finderscope shows Uranus easily, Neptune in good conditions, and some 8th magnitude deep-sky objects.

Comment: @MikeG first thanks for the edit, I rushed through that first bit and clearly didn't read some bits properly! Second, yes, you *can* see those things through a 8x50 finderscope but it has to be great conditions, and 8th magnitude DSOs will just be a tiny blur, hence why I said the best bet is to go for the brighter ones. I tried to mention targets that would get the most "wow" factor from the mentioned scope